# why my C++ main() doesn't take my parameters

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program running in Fedora 20. It can take no parameter or one parameter when I start it via the main(). Now I need more parameters but somehow, it refuse to take the new parameters.

This is how I start it:

**$ ./runtest.sh ire 22 33**

This is the first line cout inside the main():

**UICommTest is starting ... argc=2**

I expect the argc=4.

This is my main():

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    std::cout << "UICommTest is starting ... argc="<< argc << std::endl;

    if(argc == 1)
    {
        UICommTest::startTest(false);
    }
    else if(argc == 2)
    {
        if(string(argv[1]) == "true")
        {
            UICommTest::startTest(true);
        }
        else if(string(argv[1]) == "ire")
        {
            UICommTest::startTestIRE("-1", "-1");
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Usage:: ..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if(argc == 4)
    {
        if(string(argv[1]) == "ire")
        {
            UICommTest::startTestIRE(argv[2], argv[3]);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Usage:: ..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Usage:: ..." << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I do clean and make several times. And I am sure the new changes are in. Anybody can help about this?

Comment: runtest.sh is a shell script or the name of your program?

Comment: Make sure `runtest.sh` invokes your executable with all parameters included. Simple example `exec a.out $*`

Comment: your sh probably consumes your parameters you input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a shell script `runtest.sh`, it seems. In it you probably have a line like this (path may be something longer than just `./`):

```
./UICommTest "$1" "$2"
```

It should be apparent that this will give your program only 2 arguments. Change that line to this:

```
./UICommTest "$@"
```

Note: Using the `"$@"` is important detail, it has the special feature, that it expands to equivalent of `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`. The quotes are important, so that if you pass a parameter with spaces, it still remains as one parameter.